# Template parameter denoting "something callable with particular signature"

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

I wanted the ability to write code like this:

```
SplineFunction<Polynomial<3>> cubicSplineFunction;
// ... here be some additional code to populate the above object ...

auto dydx = cubicSplineFunction.transform<Polynomial<2>>(const Polynomial<3>& cubicSpline){
    return cubicSpline.derivative();
};

auto dsdx = cubicSplineFunction.transform<T/*?*/>([](const Polynomial<3>& cubicSpline){
    Polynomial<2> dy = cubicSpline.derivative();
    Polynomial<4> dsSquared = dy*dy + 1*1;
    return [dsSquared](double x){ // Fixed in response to comment: capture by value
        return std::sqrt(dsSquared);
    };
});

dydx(1.0); // efficient evaluation of cubicSplineFunction's derivative
dsdx(2.0); // efficient evaluation of cubicSplineFunction's arc rate
```

So I implemented the classes below. But what type should I substitute for `T` (in line 8) above to denote "something callable with signature `double(double)`" ?

```
template<typename S>
struct SplineFunction {

    std::vector<S> splines;

    auto operator()(double t) const {
        int i = static_cast<int>(t);
        return splines[i](t - i);
    }

    template<typename R, typename F>
    SplineFunction <R> transform(F f) const {
        SplineFunction <R> tfs;
        for (const auto& s : splines) {
            tfs.splines.push_back(f(s));
        }
        return tfs;
    }

    // ... MORE CODE ...
}

template<int N>
struct Polynomial {
    std::array<double, N+1> coeffs;
    double operator()(double x) const;
    Polynomial<N - 1> derivative() const;

    // ... MORE CODE ...
}

template<int L, int M>
Polynomial<L+M> operator*(const Polynomial<L>& lhs, const Polynomial<M>& rhs);

template<int L>
Polynomial<L> operator+(Polynomial<L> lhs, double rhs);

// ... MORE CODE ...
```

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! The second `transform` call creates a lambda that captures a local variable by reference, then returns that lambda to the caller. What the caller gets is a lambda holding a dangling reference.

Comment: "something callable with signature `double(double)`" can be spelled as `std::function<double(double)>`

Comment: Another possibility is to drop `R` parameter entirely and have the return type deduced: `template<typename F> auto transform(F f) const -> SplineFunction<decltype(f(std::declval<S>()))> { ... }`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You can spell that with `std::function`, but only with overhead (in both performance and size). May not matter in this case but worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&(S const&)>>
SplineFunction<R> transform(F f) const
```

don't pass types expliclty; let them be deduced.

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) do `typename std::result_of<F&(S const&)>::type`.

Decaying the R type (as in std decay) may also be smart, as SplineFunction stores its template parameter, and decay makes types more suitable for storage.

Comment: In C++17, `std::result_of` is deprecated.

Comment: @daniel yes; but the reason is it is hard to use; I used it properly.  The C++2a/b version is a mechanical transformation.

Comment: I’m not saying you did use it incorrectly; I’m advocating against using deprecated features in general (it makes upgrades harder) and especially against doing so without making a note of it being deprecated. Although in this case I think both `result_of` and `invoke_result` are the wrong tools for the job and if I were at a real computer would expand [Igor Tandetnik’s return type deduction suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50125617/27302#comment87269588_50125617) into a full answer.